# Laravel form stripped in foreach loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I seem to be having a weird bug, and tbh I'm not sure where to start to get help. So the issue goes as follows:

I have an **update blade file** with following code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="images" class="control-label" style="width: 100%;">Gallery</label>
@if ($event->images)
    <div class="form-gallery">
        @foreach ($event->images as $image)
            <div class="form-gallery-item" style="background-image: url({{ asset('/storage/' . $image->file_path) }})">
                <form action="{{ url('/admin/event/image', ['id' => $image->id]) }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit" class="form-gallery-remove"><i class="fal fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="images" name="images[]" multiple>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="files" class="control-label" style="width: 100%;">Files</label>
    @if ($event->files)
        <ul class="form-files">
            @foreach ($event->files as $file)
                <li class="form-files-item">
                    <a href="{{ $file->file_path }}">{{ $file->title or $file->file_path }}</a>
                    <form action="{{ url('/admin/event/file', ['id' => $file->id]) }}" method="POST" class="form-inline">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button type="submit" class="form-file-remove"><i class="fal fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                    </form>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="files" name="files[]" multiple>
</div>
```

Now when the images or files are being populated, each of them will have a delete button. For some reason the first item that comes (whether images is empty or not), will have it's form tag stripped.

[image: rendered code]

This makes it impossible to have these delete buttons in the update parent form, cause the update form has it's method set to "DELETE" :(

If needed, **Laravel version: v5.6.38**

Comment: You likely have another form tag opened before your first form in the loop. May be post the entire blade file contents here for further inspection.

Comment: K well, I haven't really payed attention and didn't know nested forms were 'prohibited'

Comment: Chrome developer tools might render it so that it appears as though there's a missing form tag if you've nested forms. May be you can see the form by viewing source i.e. ctrl+u. Nonetheless nesting forms is a no no so just confirm that this isn't the case.

Comment: Well that's my point, these are nested. I changed the layout and all works fine now.